# Syntax highlighting for "Java Card" code?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, syntax-highlighting

Normally when we post a piece of code that is written in **Java** in our question, adding the Java tag to the question activates syntax highlighting which makes it easier to read.

I want to know if is it possible to add this feature to **Java Card** posts also? i.e. I want my code to be highlighted when I tag my question with [javacard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javacard) (and not Java).

Note that **Java** and **Java Card** are really similar (but not equal), so we should be able to have the same feature for our Java Card code, without adding the Java tag to our questions.

Comment: Note that you can add your own formatting comment (`<!-- language: lang-java -->`) to force this where it isn't already automatic.

Comment: @jonrsharpe where should I add this? Why SO community doesn't make it automatic just like Java programs?

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184108/248731. Perhaps it *will* be made automatic; this is just so you can apply the formatting you want in the meantime.